# Flutter- How to highlight all selected positions in a list

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list view with a favorite button I need to highlight all favorites clicked by the user in the list. Please help me to proceed. And thanks in advance

Comment: provide your code that you tried

Comment: Show your design layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap each item in **ListView** with a **Container** and then you can use color property to change color or highlight an item when favorite button is clicked .